# Android using 9-patch works for some buttons but not others?

Tags: java, android, button, background, nine-patch

In my main activity, I was able to use my 9-patch images for the backgrounds of the 4 main buttons by coding into the XML.

main activity xml

```
<button
    style="@style/button_default"/>
```

^ This works, and the buttons on the main activity use the button_default.xml images for the button states.

Then, I try to do the exact same thing in another activity using the exact same method, and it doesn't work.  The buttons are still the default gray.  I then tried using the java method to set the background

java file for different activity

```
//This works
buttonOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

//This does NOT work
buttonOne.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_default);
```

So, whether I try setting the background for the buttons through XML or Java, I can't get it to work.  But, I can get it to work only in the main activity.  Is this common, or is there a reason why it isn't working?

@alanv, here's the very simple style/button_default that's located in styles.xml

```
<style name="button_default">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_default</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Wouldn't say it's common. There is a reason alright, but without any code it's impossible to say really.

Comment: You could check the manifest and see if you are setting a theme on the offending activity

Comment: Post XML for @style/button_default.

Comment: @JHH, there's not a lack of "any code" up there.  I put what I thought was relevant.  Useless comment is useless. jb15613, will do, thanks. alanv, I'll post that up right now.

Comment: Like I said, it works for the main activity, but the same thing won't work for another activity?